# Get all users with a specific manager

Tags: powershell, office365

I need to have a list of all users with a specific managers.

this is what I have:

```
    $manager = Get-user -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq 'bert@contoso.com'"

    $reports = Get-User -Filter "manager eq '??????'"

    $reports | FL
```

However I can't get it to work. This script will run against a O365 cloud environment.

Comment: `Get-User` -> `Get-ADUser`, then `$reports = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(manager=$($manager.DistinguishedName)))"`

Comment: if this is in Azure AD, you can just run `Get-AzureADUserDirectReport -objectid 'bert@contoso.com'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a quick look over this an have a method which is working for myself, I tried to style it around how you had set this up originally:

```
$manager = "Display name"

$reports = get-ADUser -filter * -Properties Manager |
select Name,samaccountname, @{n="ManagerName";e={get-aduser $_.manager | 
select -ExpandProperty name}}, @{n="ManagerEmail";e={get-aduser $_.manager -properties mail | 
select -ExpandProperty mail}} 


$reports | Where-Object {$_.ManagerName -like $manager} | fl
```

This will grab everyone within your AD, it'll search for 4 main properties:

> Name
>
> Samaccountname
>
> ManagerName
>
> ManagerEmail

This will grab a list of users who match manager, you can change:

```
{$_.ManagerName -like $manager}
```

to

```
{$_.ManagerEmail -like $manager}
```

If you want to search by Email instead.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're doing anything with $reports apart from outputting to a list, in which case it's redundant. You ideally want to filter your dataset up-front with whatever criteria you have. In this case you have specific managers, but I'm guessing you can also be more specific about the OU you want to search in.:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter (|(Manager=[manager1 distinguishedname])(Manager=[manager2 distinguishedname])(Manager=[manager3 distinguishedname])) -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Properties Manager | Select Name, SAMAccountName, @{n="ManagerName";e={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name}}, @{n="ManagerEmail";e={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -properties email).email}} | FL
```